# Is there a name for the dots and forward slashes (i.e. "./", "../", "../../", etc.) at the beginning of relative file paths? What is it?

Tags: path, uri, relative-path

For clarification, I'm just talking about relative file paths that also include a directory or filename in them, for example `../../some_directory/my_file.ext`. I understand that `./` is current directory and `../` is parent directory and that on their own they are in fact relative paths.

But, I am wondering in the context of a relative path that includes directory/directories and possibly the filename and extension after the dots and slashes, what are the dots and slashes known as? The "directory referrer", "path adjuster", etc.?

I'd like to know, because I have a function that creates this portion of the relative path based on target folder's depth (which I am calling frequently throughout my app) and I'd like to give it a name that will help make my code more legible to others. Right now I'm calling them `dotSlashes` and the function is called `prependDotSlashes`.

I've googled and stackoverflowed around, but didn't find a definitive name.

If anybody knows the industry-standard name for this portion of relative file paths, I would be curious to know it.

Comment: i've always just called it a relative path, as the absolute path would not have a beginning with a ./

Comment: `.` is current directory, `..` is parent directory. I'm voting to close this as off topic because it is not specific to programming, and most of your tags are unrelated.

Comment: Okay I changed the tags. I agree, this isn't an issue specific to those languages, but to all relative file paths in programming (and non-programming) applications. I still think it's useful to know that there doesn't appear to be a name for this portion of a relative file path. I'm sure some programmers would appreciate that this question was asked and that the answer was "no".

Answer (score 2):

Man, I know the dot as "current directory", and the slashes as directory separator.

The double dots (..) is know as parent directory.

Relative path is a path *relative* to where you are. Eg: If you are in the /etc path, then, the ./apache path is a relative to that /etc. A full string path (from the root) is named absolute path. So, for example:

```
../../../../ => Relative path
/home/user/Documents/doc1 => absolute path
./Document/doc1 => relative path from home
```

Comment: Yes, but what is the whole lot called? I mean any combination of `"./"`, `"../"`, `"../../"` ... `"../../../../../../../../"` etc.? Not just those specific instances, but any and all of the possibilities?

Comment: @mepley A relative path?

Comment: @mepley `./../../` is also a valid relative path. It doesn't have a different name just because it uses some special characters.

Comment: if "./" had a more specific name then all other variations would also, making it really annoying to define , but as mentioned above, the .'s and ./'s are indicative to where , kind of like a street address. 1900 Pennsylvania dr is a street address, and 100 Pennsylvania drive is also a street address, but the number of characters tell you where on Pennsylvania Dr.

Comment: 1900 and 100 are called "house numbers" or "street numbers", correct? And the entire string "1900 Pennsylvania Dr." is called an "address" or "street address".  You wouldn't ask someone for your "address" and you reply with 1900. You wouldn't ask for a relative path and reply `"../../../"` if the full relative path is actually `"../../../some_dir/my_file.ext"` to get to the resource. @aaronlilly @Herohtar That's where I'm confused. I think about relative path as having a "referrer/adjuster" from current working directory then a "navigator" that goes thru the file system to the resource.